# MongoDB Aggregate Query to group the array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a document like the one below:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a4c7eedb1016444df846a24"), 
    "questionText" : "Question", 
    "questionType" : "XYZ", 
    "optionsAll" : [
        {
            "answerId" : ObjectId("5a4c7eedb1016444df846a23"), 
            "answerValue" : "", 
            "answerSeq" : NumberInt(1), 
            "other" : false, 
            "ratingOrder" : NumberInt(0), 
            "freeTextResponse" : "I can write anything"
        }, 
        {
            "answerId" : ObjectId("5a4c7eedb1016444df846a23"), 
            "answerValue" : "", 
            "answerSeq" : NumberInt(1), 
            "other" : false, 
            "ratingOrder" : NumberInt(0), 
            "freeTextResponse" : "I can write anything"
        }, 
        {
            "answerId" : ObjectId("5a4c7eedb1016444df846a23"), 
            "answerValue" : "", 
            "answerSeq" : NumberInt(1), 
            "other" : false, 
            "ratingOrder" : NumberInt(0), 
            "freeTextResponse" : "I can't write anything"
        }
    ], 
    "optionsUnique" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a4c7eedb1016444df846a23"), 
            "_class" : "com.Answer", 
            "answerSeq" : NumberInt(1), 
            "answerValue" : "", 
            "expected" : false, 
            "other" : false, 
            "selected" : false, 
            "version" : NumberLong(0)
        }
    ], 
    "activityId" : ObjectId("5a4c7eedb1016444df846a26")
}
```

And I want to add one more field in this document which will be "freeTextResponses" that will contain the "freeTextResponse" and it's count. Something like this below "

```
"freeTextResponses" : [
                [
                    2.0, 
                    {
                        "freeTextResponse":"I can write anything"
                    }
                ], 
                [
                    1.0, 
                    {
                        "freeTextResponse":"I can't write anything"
                    }
                ]
            ]
```

I know we can do this using mongodb aggregate queries , but I am not able to find the one which suits my requirement. Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: "add one more field" = UPDATE the document?

Comment: Yes I want to use "$addFields".

Comment: $addFields not actually update the document but using to manipulate the returned document by the query, so the changes reflect only on the query's output. with $addFields for example, you can return the sum of array field that you have on each document.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/), this not replaces your document but update it.

```
db.mycollection.update(
   {questionType: "XYZ"}, // filter which documents to update
   {$set: { // what add to the filtered documents 
      "freeTextResponses" : [
                [
                    2.0, 
                    {
                        "freeTextResponse":"I can write anything"
                    }
                ], 
                [
                    1.0, 
                    {
                        "freeTextResponse":"I can't write anything"
                    }
                ]
            ]
   });
```

Also, if you want to add elements to the `freeTextResponses` array, you should use [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/)

Comment: Michael can you please give me example for the same

Comment: @Beginner added example for you